# SMS received broadcastReceiver is not called when app is not running

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I am using a broadcastReceiver to listen SMS received even when app is not running. It is working fine on **Kitkat** even app is removed from recent Apps, But not on **Lollipop** and higher devices.

In Manifest It is defined like this.

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.MxSMSReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="5822">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Receiver code:

```
public class MxSMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED") || intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT")) {

   }
  }
 }
```

I don't know what is the problem. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: you have to get runtime permission for marshmallow and greater ! have you get them?

Comment: @SohailZahid not yet, please tell me how to do that

Comment: right now i have added these permissions in Manifest file 
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

are you talking about this ?

Comment: and it worked ? plus you also need runtime permission as suggested by @Sohail too

Comment: no it is not working. these things I am already doing. but still not working

Comment: Hey! Take a look at https://github.com/draxdave/permissioner .

Comment: runtime permission is also not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full working demo Runtime Permissions**

Change the permission name which you want to get at runtime.

`private String permission = Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS;`

> Those permssions which you want to get at runtime should also be declared in
>   manifest too.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;
    private Button button;
    private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 123;
    private String permission = Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (CheckPermission(MainActivity.this, permission)) {
                    // you have permission go ahead
                    YouCanReadContactNow();
                } else {
                    // you do not have permission go request runtime permissions
                    RequestPermission(MainActivity.this, permission, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void YouCanReadContactNow() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

        switch (permsRequestCode) {
            case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // you have permission go ahead
                    YouCanReadContactNow();
                } else {
                    // you do not have permission show toast.
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void RequestPermission(Activity thisActivity, String Permission, int Code) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                    Permission)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                        new String[]{Permission},
                        Code);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean CheckPermission(Context context, String Permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Request contact permissions"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where i should put this code.. in my receiver code ?

Comment: runtime permissions can be request only in activity.

Comment: So I have to do this in main activity i mean in Launching activity of the application. Right ?

Comment: sure :) , REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 123 can you tell me why it is 123

Comment: you can use any number 111,999 123,1122 ;its only for identifying which request is request by user.

Comment: hey i am getting permission at runtime but still receiver is not called

Answer (score 0):

```
Make sure from the following :

 android:minSdkVersion="your min"
 android:targetSdkVersion="your max" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: that is android:targetSdkVersion="23"